# Does Edge support FTP?

Tags: windows, windows-10, ftp, microsoft-edge

When trying to resolve a different problem I found that accessing an FTP-site I already have working as a network location in my Windows file explorer, I found that Edge does not access the FTP server correctly:

[image: on the left side: edge with a censored FTP URL, showing an empty page, on the right side, Internet Explorer with a censored FTP URL showing the beginning of a directory listing]
On the left side you can see Edge showing an empty page, on the right side, Internet Explorer showing the beginning of a directory listing.

I have copied over the URL from Edge into Internet Explorer. Interestingly Edge didn't even deem it necessary to prompt me for credentials and just flat out refused to do anything beyond rendering nothing...

Is Edge misconfigured (from an out of the box Windows installation)? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: No, Edge doesn't support the ftp (except anonynous login).
http://superuser.com/questions/1168797/microsoft-edge-dont-open-a-custom-ftp-link

Comment: A possible solution would be to use an actual FTP client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not edge misconfigured. Microsoft Edge currently only supports anonymous FTP login via the Internet. For FTP login over LAN, logging in using either the anonymous account or username/password is not supported.