# Microsoft Edge don't open a custom ftp link

Tags: ftp, microsoft-edge

I try to open a custom FTP link in the MS Edge in Windows 10 (with all updates): ftp://mcuser:mychat@192.168.10.2:20000/

The browser doesn't open it (error message: unable to open page). But ftp://ftp.intel.com works correctly in it.

In the Explorer/Chrome/Opera/FireFox - all ok (at the same computer).

What can I do to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. [QNAP Help: Why can I not log into NAS FTP with Microsoft Edge?](https://www.qnap.com/en/qa/con_show.php?op=showone&cid=295).

> Microsoft Edge currently only supports anonymous FTP login via the Internet. For FTP login over LAN, logging in using either the anonymous account or username/password is not supported.

A possible to solution would be to use either of those other browsers or use an actual FTP client like FileZilla or similar.

Comment: ...or just the built-in FTP client via the Windows command prompt